# 'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 107 pos 15: 'paddingg.isNonNegative' : is not true

Tags: flutter, widget

I wanted to use a custom widget that Shows up the widget, It's works fine on my one phone Redmi Note 7s but when I test it on my Redmi Note 3 it throws the error.

My code is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cpblog/detailsPage.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:cpblog/data.dart';
import 'package:cpblog/ShowUp.dart';
import 'package:marquee/marquee.dart';
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:fancy_drawer/fancy_drawer.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String category;
  final String address;
  MyHomePage({this.address,this.category});
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin{
  List<Posts> posts = List();
  List<Posts> ds = List();
  bool isLoaded = false;
  FancyDrawerController _controller;
  int delayAmount = 500;

  Future<void> _fetchData() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(widget.address);
      if(response.statusCode==200){
        final data = json.decode(response.body);
        posts = (data['articles'] as List).map((data){  
          return Posts.fromJSON(data);
        }).toList();
        setState(() {
        this.isLoaded = true;
      });
      }
    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }
  
  void initState() {
    _fetchData();
    super.initState();
    _controller = FancyDrawerController(
      vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250))
    ..addListener(() {
      setState(() {}); // Must call setState
    });
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose(); // Dispose controller
  super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Material(
          child: FancyDrawerWrapper(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white, // Drawer background
        controller: _controller,
        drawerItems: <Widget>[ListTile(
          title: Text('Algorithms',style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: width*0.063)),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => MyHomePage(address:'*********',category: 'Algorithms',)));
          },
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Data Structures',style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: width*0.063)),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => MyHomePage(address:'******************',category: 'Data Structures',)));      
          },
        ),], 
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(elevation: 0.0,backgroundColor:Color(0xFF21BFBD),
            leading: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.menu,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: height*0.043,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  _controller.toggle();
                },
              ),),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF21BFBD),
          body: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.0037, left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.49),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.1017),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.337,),
                        child: ShowUp(
                          child: Text(
                            'Blogs',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: width*0.059)),
                      delay: delayAmount,      
                        ),
                      ),
                    SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.0130),
                    Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: ShowUp(
                              child: Text('For You',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: width*0.079)),
                         delay: delayAmount+200,         
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),      
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.041),
              Row(
                children: [
                  widget.category=='Algorithms'?SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.502,):SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.421,),
                  Expanded(
                      child: ShowUp(
                          child: AutoSizeText(widget.category,
                          maxLines: 1,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: width*0.076)),
                      delay: delayAmount+=100,         
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),  
              SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.0124),
              Expanded(
                    child: ShowUp(
                    child: Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.781,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(75.0),topLeft: Radius.circular(75.0)),
                    ),
                    child: ListView(
                      primary: false,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.0636, right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.050),
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.055),
                            child: RefreshIndicator(
                            child:isLoaded?Container(                             
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.625,
                                child: ListView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap:true,
                                  itemCount:posts.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context,index)
                                  {return ShowUp(
                                        child: _buildFoodItem(posts[index].image,posts[index].title,posts[index].content,posts[index].text,
                                    posts[index].video1,posts[index].video2,posts[index].video3,posts[index].video4),delay: delayAmount+60,
                                  );})):Center(
                                  child: CircularProgressIndicator()
                                  ),onRefresh: _fetchData,)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildFoodItem(String imgPath, String foodName,String url,String text,String video1,String video2,String video3,String video4) {
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-372.0, right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-372.0, top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-793.0),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            print(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height);
            print(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width);
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => DetailsPage(heroTag: imgPath, foodName: foodName,url: url,text: text,video1: video1,video2: video2,video3: video3,video4: video4)));
          },
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Hero(
                      tag: imgPath,
                      child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              image: NetworkImage(imgPath),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-733.0,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-312.0)
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.025),
                    Container(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.0186,
                            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.42),
                            child: AutoSizeText(
                              foodName,
                              maxLines: 1,
                              overflowReplacement: Marquee(
                                text: foodName,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                scrollAxis: Axis.horizontal,
                                blankSpace: 20.0,
                                velocity: 30.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                  ]
                )
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                color: Colors.black,
                onPressed: () {Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => DetailsPage(heroTag: imgPath, foodName: foodName,url: url,text: text,video1: video1,video2: video2,video3: video3,video4: video4)));}
              )
            ],
          )
        ));
  }
}
```

My custom widget code is

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ShowUp extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final int delay;

  ShowUp({@required this.child, this.delay});

  @override
  _ShowUpState createState() => _ShowUpState();
}

class _ShowUpState extends State<ShowUp> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animController;
  Animation<Offset> _animOffset;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _animController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    final curve =
        CurvedAnimation(curve: Curves.decelerate, parent: _animController);
    _animOffset =
        Tween<Offset>(begin: const Offset(0.0, 0.35), end: Offset.zero)
            .animate(curve);

    if (widget.delay == null) {
      _animController.forward();
    } else {
      Timer(Duration(milliseconds: widget.delay), () {
        _animController.forward();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _animController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FadeTransition(
      child: SlideTransition(
        position: _animOffset,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
      opacity: _animController,
    );
  }
}
```

and Exception or the error thrown is

```
Reload already in progress, ignoring request
Restarted application in 4,106ms.

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
[38;5;244mThe following assertion was thrown building SlideTransition(animation: AnimationController#c57cb(⏮ 0.000; paused)➩_DecelerateCurve➩Tween<Offset>(Offset(0.0, 0.3) → Offset(0.0, 0.0))➩Offset(0.0, 0.3), state: _AnimatedState#5cc4a):[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 107 pos 15: 'padding.isNonNegative': is not true.


[38;5;248mEither the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
[39;49m

[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mSlideTransition[39;49m
[38;5;244mWhen the exception was thrown, this was the stack[39;49m
[38;5;244m#2      new RenderPadding[39;49m
[38;5;244m#3      Padding.createRenderObject[39;49m
[38;5;244m#4      RenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#5      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m...     Normal element mounting (55 frames)[39;49m
[38;5;244m...[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 107 pos 15: 'padding.isNonNegative': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mSlideTransition[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 107 pos 15: 'padding.isNonNegative': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mSlideTransition[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 107 pos 15: 'padding.isNonNegative': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mSlideTransition[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 107 pos 15: 'padding.isNonNegative': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mSlideTransition[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 107 pos 15: 'padding.isNonNegative': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mSlideTransition[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 107 pos 15: 'padding.isNonNegative': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mSlideTransition[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 107 pos 15: 'padding.isNonNegative': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mSlideTransition[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 107 pos 15: 'padding.isNonNegative': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mSlideTransition[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 107 pos 15: 'padding.isNonNegative': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mSlideTransition[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 107 pos 15: 'padding.isNonNegative': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mSlideTransition[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 107 pos 15: 'padding.isNonNegative': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mSlideTransition[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 107 pos 15: 'padding.isNonNegative': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mSlideTransition[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m
```

The problem is in my custom widget but it works on some device and fails on some, how to overcome this error and if this error can't be fixed is there any other work around to get the same result as the custom widget?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think the problem is in the offset.

Comment: Yes I do know it but I'm not able to figure it out what is the problem,offset is just creating the delay animation orientation....